# Understanding Constructor initializer list

Tags: c++11, constructor

I am learning about Constructors. One part I am confused about is the initializer list portion of a constructor. For example take a look at the below code

```
class a{

Public:

 typedef std::string::size_type pos;
 s() = default;
 s(pos ht, pos wt, char c) : height(ht), width(wt), contents(ht * wt, c);

private:
  pos height, width;
  std::string contents;
};
```

the part I do not understand/cannot read is the last list initializer `contents(ht * wt, c)` I have never seen a list initializer with 2 arguments(?) in it. how do I read `contents(ht * wt, c)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialization list calls constructors, so this calls [constructor of `contents` that accepts two arguments](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/string/) (fill constructor in the link).